# File.SaveBinaryDirect saving file without content

Tags: office-365, csom, docx

I am trying to save a file to SharePoint using the below code

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx,serverRelativeUrl,stream,true)
```

This saves the file to the path, but when I open the file, there is no content. 
But when I check the stream before executing that line it was not empty

Comment: facing exactly the same issue after two years of your post.. have you found any solution this??

Comment: I think I was missing a ctx.ExecuteQuery()  after this. Try adding it and see if it resolves the issue

Comment: No still the same empty document is created no change after adding ctx.ExecuteQuery()